# ServiceNow JavaScript [ Auto populate email connected to user on form]

Tags: javascript, arrays, email, servicenow, auto-populate

Please help! Trying to learn how to auto populate the email connected to whom the user is active on the hardware form.

NA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.  It sounds like it could be Service Catalog, but there are many ways to implement a "form".  We need more details before we can suggest a solution.